# Auto login to Symfony 5 from another Symfony 5 website?

Tags: symfony, symfony5.4

I work on two sites that I created with symfony 5.4.

On the first site I have a list of users with their login credentials (firstname and lastname, no password needed).

When I click on a link, I would like to open the second site in a new tab and be automatically logged in as the selected user by passing his login credentials.

I tried by sending credentials in the url :

```
<a href:"https://myWebsite2.com?lastname=Foo&firstname=Bar" target='_blank'>
```

and trying to get them back in my UserAuthenticator :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $lastname = $request->query->has('lastname') ? $request->query->get('lastname') : $request->request->get('lastname');
    $firstname = $request->query->has('firstname') ? $request->query->get('firstname') : $request->request->get('firstname');
    ...      
}
```

But it doesn’t work and I don’t think that’s the solution

I looked online for solutions but I found nothing. Could you tell me if it is possible to do that and if so, could you give me the steps to follow to do so ? Thank you

Comment: “I tried by sending credentials in the url” So anyone can impersonate any user? You can try to use something like this: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/login_link.html site2 may have to call site1 in order to check the token. Or use Oauth.

Comment: Like A.L says you can use Passwordless Login Link (symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/login_link.html) or you can use a JSON login if your other Symfony application have an API login ( thanks to that : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#json-login ). Otherwise you can create an api connexion using this link : https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: Thank you for your help this has helped me a lot. I set up a Passwordless Login Link and it works perfectly.